# Using Ajax does load div, but it changes position. How can I use replaceWith?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, refresh, replacewith

I am using this function to refresh a part of my page, but the problem is that it's loading the ul#bla twice, which forces the list to change position by going to the right.

How can I use this function to replace ul#bla with itself? By using replaceWith? If so, how? I can't get it working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        jQuery('ul#bla').fadeOut("fast").load("testpage.php ul#bla").fadeIn("fast");
    }, 2000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        jQuery('ul#bla').fadeOut("fast", function () {
            jQuery(this).load("testpage.php ul#bla", function () {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

`fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` and `load()` are sync in jQuery so you need to place them in callback of each other.

Comment: It says `missing } after function body`. I tried this `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
       jQuery('ul#bla').fadeOut("fast", function () {
    jQuery(this).load("testpage.php ul#bla").fadeIn("fast");
});

});`

Comment: Of course, you are missing one `})`. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Hieu, but it does not replace the `ul`. It now puts a `ul` beneath the `ul` instead of replacing it. Can you fix that, please?

Comment: But that won't fix the DOM issue? It puts it beneath the ul, instead of replacing it. Making it go faster or slower does not make sense to me?

Comment: Ah I see, adding an `empty()` would do (when the ul is hiding). Answer updated.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this problem? Still getting it beneath the ul instead of replacing it.

Comment: @Johan I'm please sure it would be done this time, answer updated. You can check this fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/JLB6c/

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty the container before loading again.

```
$(function() 
{
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        var $container = $('ul#bla');

        $container.fadeOut("fast");
        $container.empty();
        $container.load("testpage.php ul#bla");
        $container.fadeIn("fast");

    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but not the way I want, because this is too obtrusive. It removes the whole thing and then it puts in there, but that's not stylish. Is there any way it can just refresh the list items that are in there? Or the whole ul without emptying it?

Comment: Without seeing a demo it would be hard to give you a more precise answer but normally where you load your result ie '$('ul#bla')' isn't the same name of the selector i.e 'load("testpage.php ul#bla")' your searching in the document. try having two different names.

Comment: I did try that, but it's not working the way I want. You can just fiddle it, it's simple: I have an ul and a list. That's it. I want to refresh the ul.